# ionic2 frame work sending empty parameters in post(400 Badrequest)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**login.ts**

```
onlogin() {
    let login_email = "vvvv@gmail.com";
    let login_password = "123456"
    this.body = {
        login_email: login_email,
        login_password: login_password
    };

    this.auth.login(this.body).subscribe(data => {
        this.result = data
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

**authservice.ts**

```
login(param) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/login', JSON.stringify(param), options)
    .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
            return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
        }
    });
}
```

Method is working fine in postman but, while sending the same request from ionic2 is generating an error.Get methods  were working fine but there is some issue in post.The request is sending empty parameters in post and generating error 400 Bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Login.ts**

> onlogin()
>       {
>
> ```
> const email = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
> const password = '123456';
> let body = new FormData();
> body.append("login_email",email);
> body.append("login_password",password);
>
>         console.log(body); 
>         this.auth.login(body).subscribe(data => {this.result = data;
>        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage,{result:this.result});
>     });
>
>
> }
> ```

**authservice.ts**

> ```
>    login(param) 
>   {
>    const headers = new Headers({'ContentType':'application/formdata'});
>    return this.http.post('/api',param,headers)
>                 .map(this.extractDataLogin)       
>                 .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
>    }
> ```

Using formdata to send data resolved my problem

> ```
> let body = new FormData();
> body.append("login_email",email);
> body.append("login_password",password);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You debugged the request and it is sent with an empty body? I am not sure if this actually makes a difference, but I pass the object which should be sent to the server directly as second parameter to the post() method without using JSON.stringify(). Did you already try to omit that part?

Comment: Yes,I tried this with out using json.stringify ,I got the same error.Handling the error using catch block generates "TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."